# Is it possible to perform load Testing on Mobile Apps

Tags: android, performance-testing, load-testing, mobile-application

Anyone please guide me how I perform load testing on Android Applications. Please suggest any tool with guidelines.

Comment: Sorry, asking for tool recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to test Android application performance **itself**, i.e. find the slowest functions, measure activities switching/rendering/calculation speed, CPU, RAM, Battery usage and so on - the best (if not only) way is using a profiler tool:

- [The Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)
- [Profile your app performance](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile)

---

If your goal is to simulate hundreds/thousands of users concurrently using multiple instances of the mobile application which communicates with the backend or database, to wit you need to conduct performance testing of the backend - it's also possible with a special load testing tool.

The choice of the tool depends on several factors, the main of them are:

- [Network protocol(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) used by your application
- Ability of the tool to be run in [clustered mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) in case if one instance is not powerful enough to create the necessary load

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) for example tools comparison